# Uploading Images to a server

Tags: mysql, image-uploading, web-hosting

I am making a website which has a forum where people can fill up data and also upload their images (5mb at max). I want to know that where should these images should be stored (like on the server or some cloud)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing images on the cloud will be better cause is it much safer and efficient .

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would suggest to use id.It's the better way to store your **heavy file** upload with cloud like below way.

```
www.images.com/users/1234/
```

**Edited Answer**

Package Use in my case (i.e.http://image.intervention.io/).

```
  public function upload_image(Request $request){

   $user = User::auth();

   $file            = $request->file('image');
    $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/'.$user->id);
    $fileName        = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
    $imageResize     = Image::make($file->getRealPath())
                    ->resize(150,150,function($c){$c->aspectRatio(); $c->upsize();})->save($destinationPath.'/'.$fileName);
}
```

Comment: can you guide me a bit further like how would I then link the image on the cloud to mysql so that if somebody else wants to see it then it should be visible on the forum along with the other details

Comment: @JunaidKhan Answer is updated now.